# How to get heroku to detect nodejs buildpack?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am trying to deploy a web app to heroku but keep getting this error:

```
`-----> Failed to detect app matching https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/nodejs.tgz buildpack`
```

Here is a simplified look my app file structure:

```
myProject
|__server
    |__server.js
|__react_component_1
|__react_componet_2
|__styles</p>
```

The express server is the server.js inside the server directory and it will the entry way to my app.

It seems like this question has been asked many times before and I've read all the answers, here's what I have tried:

I am deploying from the root folder, myProject, which did not have a package.json file. I've tried npm init to set up a package.json so heroku can detect the app as nodejs. I've also made sure that package.json is being tracked by git. I've made a Procfile: `web: cd server && npm run start`. I have run the command in the cli to set buildpack: `heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs` but so far none of it has worked. I've also tried `buildpacks:clear` after setting everything up to see if heroku can automatically detect buildpacks now that I have a package.json.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Please past the output of what shows in your terminal after entering `heroku logs -n 300` to show the most recent 300 lines of log output. Something there might give a clear reason what's causing the issue

Comment: I'm not allowed to edit my comment for some reason. Meant to say "paste" the output, not past

Answer (score 0):

According to Heroku's relevant [documentation on Node.js buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#activation):

> The Heroku Node.js buildpack is employed when the application has a package.json file in the root directory.

Based on your Procfile content, `web: cd server && npm run start`, that looks like you ran npm init inside the server directory, not the root directory.

I think if you move `package.json` and the `node_modules` folder one directory down to the root, the buildpack issue will be resolved. Just make sure to change your `Procfile` to `web: npm run start` because it would be the same directory now.

Comment: Hi Pat, thank you for the answer - the server folder and both of the react component folder each have their own package.json, i ran npm init when i scaffolded the project, but did not run npm init in the root folder (myProject). I did, however, run npm init when i ran into this problem. Just for the heck of it while I was waiting for answers after posting this, I moved the content of the server folder to the root folder(myProject), and when i try to deploy, i get the same message.

Comment: **continued ** I then restored everything, cd'ed into the root folder, deleted my heroku app, ran `heroku create` one more time to see if it's my project structure issue, same problem. I hope that provides more information. Thank you once again.

Comment: Why do both react component folders have their own package.json?

Comment: because they both use webpack to output a .js file which is served on individual view templates in the server directory

Comment: If you have a front-end React.js project (what the React components would be for) and a separate Node.js project for your back-end API, I suggest setting them up as two separate Heroku projects to reduce coupling. Or even put your front-end site in a AWS S3 bucket for [static web hosting](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html)

Comment: that sounds like a good idea, I was considering that as an alternative until I realized I couldn't even deploy the server folder alone (and I just gave it another try, same error).

Comment: Do you have a separate `Procfile` inside your server folder? You would need that with `web: npm run start` in it.

Comment: Thanks for continuing to respond, Pat, I appreciate iyour help very much, and yes, I made a Procfile inside the server folder, still the same error and it's quite baffling.